# Can you develop a gluten structure by kneading matzoh meal dough?

Tags: bread, molecular-gastronomy, jewish-cuisine

I'm interested in applying principles of dough magic to Passover cooking and I have sort of a general understanding of how developing the gluten structure works when kneading a traditional wheat flour dough.

My question is whether there is any further development of the gluten structure possible when the "flour" is matzoh meal, which is basically flour that has been combined with water, baked quickly, and then ground back into flour. I assume there's a reason that there's no family recipe for "matzoh bread" but I don't know if that's religious (bc we're supposed to eat matzoh *instead* of bread and all the restrictions on yeast and all) or culinary (bc making bread-like food from matzoh meal just doesn't work).

Will a gluten structure develop at all within the matzoh meal dough? What's the chemistry of how matzoh meal doughs and batters stick together?

Answer (score 4):

Matzah meal has already been cooked and so therefore is no longer flour and cannot possibly "rise" or become leavened.  That is why any passover cakes you will make need to have egg whites separated - that is what created the leavened texture.  Think of matzah meal like bread crumbs, whatever you could use breadcrumbs for, you can use matzah meal for and vice versa.  Whatever you could NOT use breadcrumbs for (baking bread for instance) you could not use matzah meal for.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the cooked material when ground and rehydrated isn't the same? What chemically is going on?

Comment: selena T can you explain "cannot possibly "rise" or become leavened". That is not the same as develop gluten. There are other way to leaven baked goods, Baking soda, Baking powder. Cakes are leavened with these things and no gluten development. I would think that if you used matzah meal like corn meal you could "leaven it" even with no gluten development.

Comment: I'm used to using matzoh meal like breadcrumbs and I'm familiar with a bunch of traditional Ashkenazi Pesach recipes but my question is specifically about the mechanics/chemistry of the ways in which it does and does not bind.

Comment: @DoubleAA the short explanation is indeed "it has been cooked" - you cannot expect cooked food to be the same as uncooked. The long explanation needs its own question, it is not a matter to put in a single sentence.

Comment: @rumtscho Matza is just water and flour. If I get something wet and dry it out, it's often the same. It's possible that the heat is relevant, but I think this case is sufficiently more reasonable than usual to expect the cooked and uncooked versions to be functionally similar. In any event, a long answer here would be wonderful too. StackExchange can certainly handle that.

Comment: @DoubleAA "It's possible that the heat is relevant" - yes it is, and the answer already stated it. " StackExchange can certainly handle that" - it happens sometimes on StackExchange, but that's not the best way. We want the information to be where people expect it, and people don't expect the "what happens to dough when baked" information to be in a question about matzah. It is much better that it goes into its own question. This answer is very good as it is.

Comment: "What's the chemistry of how matzoh meal doughs and batters stick together?" isn't really answered by "Because it's been cooked" however true the latter statement may be. I specified pretty clearly that I wanted a more detailed explanation, as well as using the molecular-gastronomy tag. A question about matzoh is different to a question about bread dough because matzoh is more like hardtack, lacking things like oil that could affect the chemistry.

Comment: @beth indeed, the chemistry of matzoh balls is not answered by "because it has been cooked". My reading is that DoubleAA requested an explanation of the chemistry of uncooked flour, in case it is the same as the chemistry of matzoh balls. I pointed out that it is not the same, "because it has been cooked" is enough to establish why the chemistry of raw flour is not needed in an answer of matzoh chemistry, and the chemistry of raw flour is an interesting topic in itself, but if you want to read about it, you should ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Cooked wheat flour hardly develops any gluten structure anymore. This is intentionally used in many culinary techniques where you want to limit or inhibit gluten development: roux, certain flatbreads, certain pie crusts... An experiment you can do is kneading up two simple doughs, one with room temperature water one with boiling water - then separating starch and gluten by washing out the dough. The amount of gluten you can salvage from the boiling water dough will be drastically lower....