# Can you grind Cheerios and use it as flour?

Tags: baking, substitutions, bread

After reading [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/80808/57325), I was wondering if a similar procedure would work with something like Cheerios. Could I grind it up and use it as gluten-free flour for bread or Matzah? Or would it not hold?

Comment: Can you please use your question to explain why this isn't a duplicate? What makes Cheerios different? Is there a reason you're expecting this to not have the same answer? I don't personally see a reason to expect a vastly different result - not for yeast breads but would probably be fine for a quick bread.

Comment: @Catija No clue how Cheerios are made, if there's a difference between that and Matzah that would make a difference.

Comment: you'd likely need some sort of gum to hold it together, as it'd have lost any sort of ability to bind.

Comment: That's the sort of thing I'm hoping you can add. SE really loves it when the people asking questions do some of their own research and explain their questions more thoroughly. You can easily find out how Cheerios are made, what they're made from etc... use that information to explain why you think they are different.

Comment: I think the problem here is that the answers are just going to repeat the same kinds of things that were said on the other question. I know you didn't necessarily know that before asking, but duplicative answers are not ideal either way.

Comment: Seems like a really expensive way to get flour.

Comment: Cheerios are not truly guaranteed to be gluten-free, even if it says "gluten-free" on the box.  It may be very unwise for anyone with celiac disease to eat Cheerios.  Please see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Celiac/comments/8wbn05/do_you_eat_chex_cheerios_gluten_free_cereal/e1u7bdc/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/glutenfree/comments/9leoyh/cheerios_glutenfree/e768j8h/), and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/glutenfree/comments/9r0nsy/cheerios_gluten_free_labeling_needs_to_be_removed/).

Comment: Cheerios are not universally considered kosher for Passover, so may not be usable for matzah from a philosophical perspective. But that doesn't really answer what will happen in cooking :)

Comment: @Erica You’re correct that a Jew can’t have Cheerios on Passover, but that doesn’t prevent one from having matzah or a matzah-like cracker on any other day of the calendar.

Answer (score 4):

This would behave like a literal *gluten-free flour* (as in, a flour that offers no glue proteins or other binders of any kind), NOT like a complete *gluten-free flour substitute*.

Also, unlike some raw starchy flours that have no gluten (eg rice flour), there is not much binding action from sticky starches that can still gelatinize, since whatever starches are in that kind of processed cereal are likely completely cooked - otherwise, the cereal would become thoroughly sticky when mixed with a liquid like milk. The only binding properties you could maybe expect would be from sugar getting dissolved and recrystallized or caramellized into a firm matrix.

So, this could act as a filler or flavour/texture addition, but not as the only constituent of a dough or batter.

BTW, grinding up broken product (when it is still hygienically acceptable, obviously!) and adding it to the next batch is a practice sometimes used in commercial (factory level) cookie making.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use ground cheerios as a gluten-free flour for Mazto if it is only the oat-flour part of a recipe.

Typically 1 cup GF flour to 1/2 oat flour. may need a bit more liquid.

For a quick bread or steamed bread, needs a binder as in the link.